# Fetching file from Dropbox immediately after linking fails

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox

In an iOS app I'm building, I'm getting some strange behavior around linking with Dropbox. This is in Xcode 7.2, using the Dropbox iOS SDK 1.3.1.13.

First of all, when testing in the simulator, when I call `DBSession.sharedSession().linkFromController`, the console logs an error message:

> canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-2://1/connect" - error: "(null)"

Since this comes from the SDK, I can't pinpoint the source of the warning. But since the app authenticates successfully, I can't tell if this is really just a red herring.

The bigger problem is that after the app authenticates with Dropbox (as detected in `application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject))`, I call `restClient.loadFile` with the path to my app's one and only file (which I can see is in the app's folder on my Mac), and consistently get an error in the delegate method `restClient(client: DBRestClient!, loadFileFailedWithError error: NSError!)`:

> [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/sandbox/Data File.pwd - (401) Authentication failed.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the `loadFile` call. If I call it from a different method, it successfully fetches the file. It also works correctly in the OSX version of this app that shares the same custom Dropbox controller.

Can somebody tell me if I'm doing something wrong here, or if I need to come up with a workaround for a bug in the service or the SDK?

Comment: The first error is unrelated. It's just due to new restrictions on `canOpenURL` in iOS 9. The error is reported as null, so there's no issue there. Can you share your code for the 401 issue though?

Comment: Actually, I can share the solution. By re-setting the sharedSession after getting the successful authentication notification, but before attempting to load the file, it works. I'm guessing that the problem had to do with attempting to load the file with a session that didn't _know_ it was authenticated.